# How would I implement IDisposable in this context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, idisposable

I'm using Entity Framework 4 along with MSSQL to store and access data on my Windows Forms application.

Here is an example class I use to access data:

```
public class StudentRepository : IDisposable
{
    ColegioDBEntities db = new ColegioDBEntities();

    public IQueryable<Student> FindAllStudents()
    {
        return db.Students;
    }

    public Student FindStudent(int id)
    {
        return db.Students.SingleOrDefault(c => c.StudentId == id);
    }

    public void Add(Student Student)
    {
        db.AddToStudents(Student);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And here's an example of how I use it.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();
    var result = repo.FindAllUsers().Where(u => u.Username == txtUsername.Text && u.Password == txtPassword.Text);
    if (result.Count() > 0)
    {
        MainForm form = new MainForm(txtUsername.Text);
        form.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta.",
        "Acceso Denegado",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Stop,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        txtUsername.Focus();
        txtPassword.Focus();
    }
}
```

Someone suggested that I use IDisposable to properly "clean up" the connection, but I don't know how to implement this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I really got the point, but you seem to implement `IDisposable`, but you need to call `Dispose` or use `using`:

```
  using(UserRepository repo = new UserRepository())
  {
    // ...
  }
```

This calls Dispose when leaving the using block and cleans up the UserRepository.

There is some more information:

- [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)
- [Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

Comment: Ah! That was the point. :) I forgot to include the using statement so the object is disposed of. Thanks for your time. Do you recommend I do this every time I use a Repository class?

Comment: You really should ALWAYS do this when dealing with IDisposable types. You get memory leaks and probably bad side effects if you don't.

Comment: Yes of course, every instance of a class which can be disposed should get disposed after using it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it `StudentRepository` or `UserRepository`? And if one derives from the other then you have a problem.

Without inheritance your implementation of StudentRepository is acceptable. To be totally correct you should make sure by declaring it sealed:

```
public sealed  class StudentRepository : IDisposable
{
    ....
    public void Dispose()
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And, as @Stefan already pointed out, you have to make use of it every time you instantiate a StudentRepository, with `using() { }`.